generating URLs with VSTACK (or HSTACK)
I am trying to generate URLs with HYPERLINK inside a VSTACK (or HSTACK).
The following is working, generating URL (blue text underlined) for every row:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,HYPERLINK("https://<snip>"&A1:A,A1:A)))

However, when I put that in a VSTACK, this does not work anymore, the link_label is generated, but the link (blue text underlined) is not generated
=VSTACK("", ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,HYPERLINK("https://<snip>"&A1:A,A1:A))))

Any idea ?

I manage to circumvent the issue, by using Curly-brace Array Formulas. The following is working fine:
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,HYPERLINK("https://<snip>"&A1:A,A1:A)))}

